# Raspberry Pi - SSH access denied

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I am currently trying to deploy DietPi (www.dietpi.com) on my Pi, but SSH access seems to fail from Windows 10 client (both using PuTTY as well as Bitvise SSH client). Output from a linux server in my home network, that I tried to use as a gateway.

Anyone an idea why I am getting this? It is the first boot so I expect the default access and password (root & dietpi) to be correct and get me into the box.

Thanks!

```
root@openmediavault:~# ssh -v root@192.168.0.214
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.214 [192.168.0.214] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 9d:ac:18:9c:44:e6:98:82:d5:0d:f9:6c:fb:ec:98:d6
debug1: Host '192.168.0.214' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.0.214's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Answer (score 1):

root logins are often disabled by default for SSH. Check the PermitRootLogin option in sshd_config. You may enable root logins by setting this option to yes, but doing so is not recommended, especially with password authentication.

Comment: Thanks! Normally it does not make any probs, the release is designed to log in as root by default.